# Bash: Working with CSV file to build a loop and save the result

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

Using Bash, I'm wanting to get a list of email addresses from a CSV file to do a recursive `grep` search on it for a bunch of directories looking for a match in specific metadata XML files, and then also tallying up how many results I find for each address throughout the directory tree (i.e. updating the tally field in the same CSV file).

`accounts.csv` looks something like this:

###### updated to more accurately reflect real-world data

```
email,date,bar,URL,"something else",tally
address@somewhere.com,21/04/2015,1.2.3.4,https://blah.com/,"blah blah",5
something@that.com,17/06/2015,5.6.7.8,https://blah.com/,"lah yah",0
another@here.com,7/08/2017,9.10.11.12,https://blah.com/,"wah wah",1
```

For example, if we put `address@somewhere.com` in `$email` from the list, run

```
grep -rl "${email}" --include=\*_meta.xml --only-matching | wc -l
```

on it and then add that result to the `tally` column.

At the moment I can get the first column of that CSV file (minus the heading/first line) using

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' accounts.csv | tail -n +2
```

but I'm lost how to do the looping *and* also the writing of the result back to the CSV file...

So for instance, with `another@here.com` if we run

```
grep -rl "${email}" --include=\*_meta.xml --only-matching | wc -l
```

and the result is say `17`, how can I update that line to become:

```
another@here.com,7/08/2017,9.10.11.12,https://blah.com/,"wah wah",17
```

Is this possible with maybe `awk` or `sed`?

This is where I'm up to:

```
#!/bin/bash

# make temporary list of email addresses
awk -F"," '{print $1}' accounts.csv | tail -n +2 > emails.tmp

# loop over each
while read email; do
    # count how many uploads for current email address
    grep -rl "${email}" --include=\*_meta.xml --only-matching | wc -l
done < emails.tmp
```

XML Metadata looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <identifier>SomeTitleNameGoesHere</identifier>
  <mediatype>audio</mediatype>
  <collection>opensource_movies</collection>
  <description>example &lt;br /&gt;</description>
  <subject>testing</subject>
  <title>Some Title Name Goes Here</title>
  <uploader>another@here.com</uploader>
  <addeddate>2017-05-28 06:20:54</addeddate>
  <publicdate>2017-05-28 06:21:15</publicdate>
  <curation>[curator]email@address.com[/curator][date]20170528062151[/date][comment]checked for malware[/comment]</curation>
</metadata>
```

Comment: The domain-part of an email address may contain a comma (see [here](https://askinglot.com/what-characters-are-valid-in-an-email-address)), so I don't think you can simply use awk with a comma as field separator.

Comment: That's a pretty epic edge-case, and doesn't apply to my data, but sure. :+1:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to do the looping and also the writing of the result back to the CSV file

`awk` does the looping automatically. You can change any field by assigning to it. So to change a tally field (the 6th in each line) you would do `$6 = ...`.
`awk` is a great tool for many scenarios. You probably can safe a lot of time in the future by investing some minutes in a short tutorial now.

The only non-trivial part is getting the output of `grep` into `awk`.

The following script increments each tally by the count of `*_meta.xml` files containing the given email address:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q=\' 'NR>1 {
  cmd = "grep -rlFw " q $1 q " --include=\\*_meta.xml | wc -l";
  cmd | getline c;
  close(cmd);
  $6 = c
} 1' accounts.csv
```

For simplicity we assume that filenames are free of linebreaks and email addresses are free of `'`.
To reduce possible false positives, I also added the `-F` and `-w` option to your `grep` command.

- `-F` searches literal strings; without it, searching for `a.b@c` would give false positives for things like `axb@c` and `a-b@c`.
- `-w` matches only whole words; without it, searching for `b@c` would give a false positive for `ab@c`. This isn't 100% safe, as `a-b@c` would still give a false positive, but without knowing more about the structure of your xml files we cannot fix this.

Comment: I see this successfully computes the tallies, but does it also write those changes to `accounts.csv`? It didn't work for me. Old data stayed the same.

Comment: No, it just *prints* the updated linux content. Either write that output to a new file `awk -F, ... accounts.csv > newAccounts.csv` which you then rename `mv newAccount.csv accounts.csv` or use GNU awk's inplace option `gawk -i inplace -F, ... accounts.csv`

Comment: PS Do you have any good `awk` tutorials to recommend?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know which tutorials are good.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using single `awk` command to achieve this. This solution will be **highly performant** as compared to other solutions because it is **scanning each XML file only once** for all the email addresses found in first column of the CSV file. Also it is not invoking any external command or spawning a sub0shell anywhere.

This should work in any version of `awk`.

```sh
cat srch.awk

# function to escape regex meta characters
function esc(s,      tmp) {
   tmp = s
   gsub(/[&+.]/, "\\\\&", tmp)
   return tmp
}
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
# while processing csv file
NR == FNR {
   # save escaped email address in array em skipping header row
   if (FNR > 1)
      em[esc($1)] = 0
   # save each row in rec array
   rec[++n] = $0
   next
}
# this block will execute for eaxh XML file 
{
   # loop each email and save count of matched email in array em
   # PS: gsub return no of substitutionx
   for (i in em)
      em[i] += gsub(i, "&")
}
END {
   # print header row
   print rec[1]
   # from 2nd row onwards split row into columns using comma
   for (i=2; i<=n; ++i) {
      split(rec[i], a, FS)
      # 6th column is the count of occurrence from array em
      print a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], em[esc(a[1])]
   }
}
```

Use it as:

```sh
awk -f srch.awk accounts.csv $(find . -name '*_meta.xml') > tmp && mv tmp accounts.csv
```

Comment: This will be much more performant than repeatedly recursively grepping a directory tree.

Comment: Could you explain what's going on here, please?

Comment: And sorry, you may also need to update it to reflect the changes to CSV...

Comment: I have added explanation along with updates to my answer to address your changed requirement. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Is the big code block above an `awk` code block? It doesn't seem to be Bash at least... I'm struggling to understand how to implement this. Do I save the contents of the code block as `srch.awk` or something? I think more detail is needed for this answer.

Comment: I have written explanation of Awk code. This is not bash code just pure Awk. Just save big code block as srch.awk and then run the command line as suggested later. Feel free to ask any specific question and I will answer

Answer (score 2):

A pipeline to reduce the number of greps:

```sh
grep -rHo --include=\*_meta.xml -f <(awk -F, 'NR > 1 {print $1}' accounts.csv) \
| gawk -F, -v OFS=',' '
    NR == FNR {
      # store the filenames for each email
      if (match($0, /^([^:]+):(.+)/, m)) tally[m[2]][m[1]]
      next
    }
    FNR > 1 {$4 = length(tally[$1])}
    1
  ' - accounts.csv
```

Comment: Brilliant! Shouldn't it be `$6 = length(tally[$1])`?

Comment: It [used to be $4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68671398/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

A script that handles `accounts.csv` line by line and replaces the data in `accounts.new.csv` for comparison.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

file_old=accounts.csv
file_new=${file_old/csv/new.csv}

delimiter=","
x=1

# Copy file
cp ${file_old} ${file_new}

while read -r line; do
        # Skip first line
        if [[ $x -gt 1 ]]; then
                # Read data into variables
                IFS=${delimiter} read -r address foo bar tally somethingelse <<< ${line}

                cnt=$(find . -name '*_meta.xml' -exec grep -lo "${address}" {} \; | wc -l)
                # Reset tally
                tally=$cnt

                # Change line number $x in new file
                sed "${x}s/.*/${address} ${foo} ${bar} ${tally} ${somethingelse}/; ${x}s/ /${delimiter}/g" \
                        -i ${file_new}
        fi

        ((x++))
done < ${file_old}
```

The input and ouput:

```
# Input
$ find . -name '*_meta.xml' -exec cat {} \; | sort | uniq -c
      2 address@somewhere.com
      1 something@that.com
$ cat accounts.csv
email,foo,bar,tally,somethingelse
address@somewhere.com,bar1,foo2,-1,blah
something@that.com,bar2,foo3,-1,blah
another@here.com,bar4,foo5,-1,blah

# output
$ ./test.sh
$ cat accounts.new.csv 
email,foo,bar,tally,somethingelse
address@somewhere.com,bar1,foo2,2,blah
something@that.com,bar2,foo3,1,blah
another@here.com,bar4,foo5,0,blah
```